# postges_fdw покдлючение к localhost, пользователь не прошел проверку подлинности по паролю

Tags: postgresql

Пытаюсь перенести данные между таблицами двух баз данных на одном postgres (12) сервере с помощью postgres_fdw.
Есть две базы source_db и dest_db, права на них - у пользователя postgres:
```
 dest_db   | postgres | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |           |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 source_db | postgres | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |           |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

В source_db создаю сервер, маппинг роли с актуальным паролем и импортирую схему dest_schema в локальную local_dest_schema:

```
create extension postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER local_dest_srv FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'dest_db', port '5432');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres SERVER local_dest_srv OPTIONS(user 'postgres', password 'password');
CREATE SCHEMA local_dest_schema;
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA dest_schema from server local_dest_srv into local_dest_schema;
```

В результате - ошибка:

```
source_db=# IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA dest_schema from server local_dest_srv into local_dest_schema;
ОШИБКА:  could not connect to server "local_dest_srv"
ПОДРОБНОСТИ:  ВАЖНО:  пользователь "postgres" не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)
```

Не подскажете, в чем может быть проблема?
Спасибо

Comment: Пользователь может заходить по удалённому соединению (`pg_hba.conf`)?

Comment: @Ainar-G , имеется в виду добавить такую строку?
host     all     all     192.168.0.10/32     password

Comment: Там всё несколько сложнее и зависит от вашего конкретного случая.  Рекомендую хорошо изучить [документацию](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), чтобы вы не открыли случайно *root*-доступ по сети на проде.

Comment: `не прошёл проверку подлинности (по паролю)` однозначно говорит, что auth method уже согласовали и выбрали использовать scram, md5 или password (без разницы). То есть база услышала запрос на подключения, потребовала предоставить пароль, но пароль вы указали неверный. Проверьте указанный в `CREATE USER MAPPING`

Comment: @Мелкий , интересно, что postgres подключается только от имени того пользователя, который сейчас залогинен в системе

Comment: да, так специально и задумано. CREATE USER MAPPING FOR public можно задат для всех